# Is Diff a well understood term, or should I name it Differentiate?

Tags: c#, naming, coding-standards

I have a class which checks for differences. I could call this

```
class ViolationDiffer
    public IEnumerable<ViolationChange> Diff(
        IEnumerable<Violation> old,
        IEnumerable<Violation> new
    );
```

Or

```
class ViolationDifferentiator
    public IEnumerable<ViolationChange> Differentiate(
        IEnumerable<Violation> old,
        IEnumerable<Violation> new
    );
```

To *diff* two text files, is so common place, that I would guess that almost everybody would understand what this did.

In the spirit of being explicit, Differentiate is just that. **Is there a rule for when a term is appropriate to shorten, as in, the shortened version is verbally used maybe?**

Comment: I think most developers will know that Diff is looking for differences between two files - on the other hand Differentiation is a mathematics term...

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: What you trying to achieve by shorter name. `differentiate` is pretty clear name. Modern IDE with IntelliSense will provide completion and you don't need to type full word

Comment: If both terms are understood equally quick, then *Diff* requires less effort to read than *Differentiate*. I don't know of any such *rule* though, but would love if someone else did.

Comment: This is a highly subjective matter, but for me `Differentiate` would require some parsing and look maybe weird, so I would vouch for either `Diff` or, as the currently only answer suggests, `Delta`. In the latter case, though, the name of the method should be something like `CalculateDelta`, because I don't think "delta" can be used as a verb.

Comment: Why use a tiny word when a diminutive one will do? :-) "Differentiator" seems excessively long assuming 'diff' is a commonly known term.

Comment: To me differentiate is to determine the rate of change *with respect to time** so 3.7 letters of change per second. Not what is the difference between 2 things. Is diff even short for differentiate as opposed to difference?

Comment: How about "Compare"?

Comment: What is wrong with a full word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Diff` and `Differ`, not `Differentiate` and `Differentiator`. The former have effectively become technical terms in programming, not abbreviations.

To me, `Differentiate` is much less clear than `Diff`, and I couldn't even say for certain that this is what "diff" originally stood for.

Comment: nitpick: `Diffor` over `Differ`, to avoid `bool differs` and `IEnumerable<Differ> differs` colliding

Comment: Most importantly: Add some documentation on top of it, so a developer can verify their interpretation of the name based on intuition with a clear-cut description of what the class is actually doing!

Comment: @Caleth I think the confusion of what looks to me like a typo outweighs the advantage of not having those names collide. I can always name the boolean `different`.

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/diff.html would indicate that 'diff' stood for 'difference'

Comment: *Diff* is certainly used as a verb though. "Just diff the text files".

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be

```
class ViolationDifferences
    public IEnumerable<ViolationChange> FindBetween(
        IEnumerable<Violation> old,
        IEnumerable<Violation> new
    );
```

which reads out in your code as

```
 IEnumerable<ViolationChange> differences =
       new ViolationDifferences().FindBetween(old, new);
```

Answer (score 0):

A (mathematical) alternative could be `Delta`.

I think there is no strict rule when to shorten and when not. It depends on who has to read (and use) your code (your audience). If you assume that an abbreviation is well accepted then it is appropriate to use it.

Another factor is how often this method is used. The more commonly it is used the more appropriate is it to abbreviate.

Comment: *"think there is no strict rule when to shorten and when not."* I argue! The (strict) rule is: when in doubt do not abbreviate...